# List of grammaticalization pathways?

Tags: reference-request

In *[On the Evolution of Grammatical Forms](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Ejim/ORIGINS/heine.kuteva.pdf)*, Heine and Kuteva show this page, without citing any sources that I could find:

[image]

They give a small sample of examples of how this might work, such as the verb "say" going to become a subordinating conjunction after evolution (sorry, the PDF is an image, so can't paste the original text).

[image]

Where can I find the research listing these "350 common grammaticalization pathways"? Where can I find more gathered collections of grammaticalization examples? I would really like to see a big set of examples of "grammaticalization", evolving from noun or verb into other POS's.

I have long been wondering if we can "get rid of prepositions", and grammaticalization points to exactly that! But in reverse, it at least shows how you can convert a preposition back into a verb or noun, which is amazing, and I would like to see more research on examples and such.

Comment: I found more elaboration on the theory in _[Grammaticalization: A Conceptual Framework](http://www.prof-bernd-heine.de/books/Heine_etal_1991_Grammaticalization.pdf)_ (also by Heine), but not a rich guide yet.

Comment: Grammaticalization more often _creates_ adpositions than _removes_ them.

Comment: I get that, that wasn't the question. I was excited because this shows a path forward on finding the original nouns/verbs from other word types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at:

Kouteva, T., Heine, B., Hong, B., Long, H., Narrog, H., & Rhee, S. (2019). *World Lexicon of Grammaticalization* (2nd ed.). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. http://doi.org/10.1017/9781316479704